# Passing object from service to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a service generated with CLI that stores an object:

```
public tutorial: Object = {
    amountMin: 5,
    amountMax: 5,
    characters: 100,
    spells: 100,
    consumable: 100,
    gold: 90
};
```

and when I import that service into the constructor of the component like this

```
constructor(
    private Packs: PacksService
) {}
```

I can `console.log(this.Packs.tutorial)` and get the object I have in the service. But if I want to use `this.Packs.tutorial.gold`, for example, it says:

```
[ts] Property 'gold' does not exist on type 'Object'. any
```

Comment: You've explicitly typed it as `Object` - why not create an interface to use instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe messing with Interfaces helped me. Not sure if the implementation is 100% correct, but it solved my problem, so thank you :)

Comment: `Object` is not what you want. That's the object constructor. Perhaps you want `object`, or nothing at all. Anyway, why did you title your question "passing object from service to component"? It seems like what you meant to ask was "accessing object in service from component", but actually your question has nothing to do with services, or components, or Angular for that matter.

Comment: @torazaburo is correct and, as he also hints at, you may want no type annotation at all. In this case, it would resolve all of your issues. Don't add types prematurely. Type-inference is very powerful and often gives you a better result especially while you're prototyping than if you had written the types by hand before you knew what their formalization would be.